# Where can I find and download of old Garageband loops online?

Tags: audio, garageband

I had an old macbook for a while and that thing crashed, along with some of my music. I got a cheap toshiba for a couple years, saved up for a Macbook Pro. I bought the Pro in 2013, didn't much of the missing loops, but i'm trying to remake an old beat (the vocals sucked). The horns I chopped up are not available on the new GB, and I don't have any backups or versions of the horns without other instruments. Try as I might, i can't replicate this sound using music software or even live brass. Anyone know where I can find these old GB loops that were around from maybe 2006-2011?

Answer (score 1):

try icompositions.com and macjams.com they both had some of the previous loops and other loops for free. If the loops were part of GB or logic or final cut pro then you can retrieve them from that software. Old versions of final cut studio 1 and 2 included the jam packs. As did logic among others. You can also try apple through a google search as they did have multiple free loops. eBay is another source or local stores.Local mac user clubs amy also be able to help. Since you owned the content you might try torrents or macserialjunkie.com